# Why a method in expression is called two times in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I want to know why a method is called two times while it is used in angularjs binding expression.

you can find my code [here at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pinuxavu/1/edit)

why the callMe() method is called two times. I found the same question already posted but
could not get a satisfactory answer. And if we want to avoid this to be called two times how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding a function to an expression

```
<p>{{callMe()}}</p>
```

that's why it's called many times, because it runs everytime when angularjs calls [digest()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest)... Here is a picture how digest work maybe it helps better...

[image]